# graphql-java - How to use subscriptions with spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql, graphql-java

In a project I use **[graphql-java](https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java)** and ***spring boot*** with a postgreSQL Database. Now I would like to use the **[subscription feature](https://graphql-java.readthedocs.io/en/latest/schema.html#subscription-support)** published in version 3.0.0. Unfortunately, the information about the application of the subsciption function is not very mature.

How is the approach to achieve **real-time functionality** using `graphql-java` with subscriptions?

Comment: Did you found a solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of recent graphql-java versions, subscriptions are fully supported. The `DataFetcher` for a subscription must return a `org.reactivestreams.Publisher`, and graphql-java will take care of mapping the query function over the results.

The feature is nicely [documented](https://www.graphql-java.com/documentation/v11/subscriptions/) and there's [a complete example](https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java-subscription-example) using web sockets available in the official repo.

If you have a reactive data source in place (e.g. Mongo with a reactive driver, or probably anything that [R2DBC](https://github.com/r2dbc) supports), you're all set. Just use [`@Tailable`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/Tailable.html) and Spring Data will already give you a `Flux` (which implements `Publisher`) and there's nothing else you need to do.

As for a more manual Spring specific implementation, I can't imagine it being too hard to use [Spring's own event mechanism](https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/11/better-application-events-in-spring-framework-4-2) (a nice tutorial [here](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-events) as well) to underlie the `Publisher`.

Every time there's an incoming subscription, create and register a new listener with the application context: `context.addApplicationListener(listener)` that will publish to the correct `Publisher`. E.g. in the `DataFetcher`:

```
// Somehow create a publisher, probably using Spring's Reactor project. Or RxJava.
Publisher<ResultObject> publisher = ...; 
//The listener reacts on application events and pushes new values through the publisher
ApplicationListener listener = createListener(publisher);
context.addApplicationListener(listener);
return publisher;
```

When the web socket disconnects or you somehow know the event stream is finished, you must make sure to remove the listener.

I haven't actually tried any of this, mind you, I'm just thinking aloud.

Another option is to use Reactor directly (with or without Spring WebFlux). There's a sample using Reactor and WebSocket (through [GraphQL SPQR Spring Boot Starter](https://github.com/leangen/graphql-spqr-spring-boot-starter)) [here](https://github.com/leangen/graphql-spqr-samples/blob/7597e2f283e103f53b094cd96220d9c53c86b7aa/spring-boot-starter-sample/src/main/java/io/leangen/graphql/samples/service/TaskService.java#L61).

You create a `Publisher` like this:

```
//This is really just a thread-safe wrapper around Map<String, Set<FluxSink<Task>>>
private final ConcurrentMultiRegistry<String, FluxSink<Task>> subscribers = new ConcurrentMultiRegistry<>();

@GraphQLSubscription
public Publisher<Task> taskStatusChanged(String taskId) {
    return Flux.create(subscriber -> subscribers.add(taskId, subscriber.onDispose(() -> subscribers.remove(taskId, subscriber))), FluxSink.OverflowStrategy.LATEST);
}
```

And then push new values from elsewhere (probably a related mutation or a reactive storage) like this:

```
subscribers.get(taskId).forEach(subscriber -> subscriber.next(task));
```

E.g.

```
@GraphQLMutation
public Task updateTask(@GraphQLNonNull String taskId, @GraphQLNonNull Status status) {
    Task task = repo.byId(taskId); //find the task
    task.setStatus(status); //update the task
    repo.save(task); //persist the task
    //Notify all the subscribers following this task
    subscribers.get(taskId).forEach(subscriber -> subscriber.next(task));
    return task;
}
```

With SPQR Spring Starter, this is all that's needed to get you an Apollo-compatible subscription implementation.

Comment: How & where would ConcurrentMultiRegistry live on a application that has multiple instances running? Is each instance expected to maintain its own subscribers & notify them?

Comment: @raga Scaling GraphQL subscriptions is notoriously difficult because it invariably involves maintaining connections and state. Since subscriptions are client-initiated, and create a persistent connection to a node, I think each node must maintain it's own subscriber registry with the client connected to it.

Comment: Got it, Thanks. If such node goes down I assume clients would need to have a way to know its down as well as re-subscribe to another running node, am i correct ?

Comment: @raga Yes. The client's connection would drop when the node goes down, and it's common for clients to immediately try re-subscribing. I'd expect a reverse-proxy on the server that transparently makes sure to direct the connection to a live node.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue where I was spiking on the lib to integrate with spring boot. I found graphql-java, however, it seems it only support 'subscription' on schema level, it is not perform any transnational support for this feature. Meaning you might need to implement it your self.

Please refer to https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java/blob/master/docs/schema.rst#subscription-support

Answer (score -1):

For the record: here is another very nice, compact example that implements GraphQLs essential features queries, mutations and subscriptions: https://github.com/npalm/blog-graphql-spring-service